ErrImageNeverPull getting this error while getting pods
When I am trying to run kubectl apply -f posts.yaml command then my post pod is created sucessfully but when I am trying get post then getting staus of pod is ErrImageNeverPull
Here is my yaml config file
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: posts
spec:
  containers:
    - name: posts
      image: chatan/demo:0.0.1
      imagePullPolicy: Never

And yes I am using windows os.
This is status is shwoing when trying to run
kubectl get pods


What code produces that PNG file?  If you've set imagePullPolicy: Never, how are you guaranteeing that the image is on every node the Pod might run on?

Sorry @DavidMaze I am not getting your question. The thing is I have created pod using this given code then trying to run kubectl get pods then getting this status which is given in image

kubectl commands never create image files, though, they write out plain text.  If the image is the kubectl output, can you [edit] the question to replace the image with plain text?  imagePullPolicy: Never is a slightly unusual setup, why do you have it and why do you believe you shouldn't get ErrImageNeverPull?

If you are using imagePullPolicy: Never the image should be present on the cluster.
Try to remove the imagePullPolicy and make sure you have provided enough credentials for the authentication part if it's a private image.
